# auto adjust perant div width to sum of its children width

Tags: css

I want to have searchBox div element width to be sum of all its child divs.
Currently I have calculated using javascript.

Is there any way that it can be set automatically using css.

Can any one please share if it is possible.

```
<div class="searchBoxHolder">
    <div class="searchBox">
        <div class="searchBoxElem">#BANANA</div>
        <div class="searchBoxElem">Grapes</div>
        <div class="searchBoxElem">fruit</div>
        <div class="searchBoxElem">mango</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nath/UdY6k/

Comment: did u tried width:auto for search box?

Comment: @Kiran : auto width of div elements is 100%

Answer (score 1):

Don't add width to wrapper and change it's display to `inline-block` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/UdY6k/1/)

***Future note:*** to remove one whites-pace gap between floated elements, add `</div><!-- --><div class='searchBoxElem'>`, or use 0px font-size for wrapper

Comment: This is good.. except I'd get rid of the floats completely, and have the .searchBoxElem as 'inline-block' also.. plus you can use white-space:nowrap to keep all elements on the same line regardless of container width.

Comment: Actually in my requirement searchBoxHolder[wrapper] width will be fixed and searchBox width should be varied based on the childrens width.

Comment: @user2810999 so it is. Since you don't specify `.searchBox` width and make it `inline-box` it will take as much space as it's inner elements.

Answer (score 0):

replace your css with this, this might would be best for you

```
.searchBoxHolder {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}


.searchBoxElem {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(251, 238, 203);
}
```